# how to deactivate some answers in multiple choice grid google form

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a multiple-choice grid in a google form. the grid is for registering people on activities at different time slots.
I've got activities in columns like yoga, dance, tennis and time slots in rows like 1:00pm 2:00pm....

is there a way to deactivate some of the checkboxes? 
I've got a limited capacity on some activities, for example when 8 people have register for yoga at 1:pm, i'd like to deactivate this option.

Comment: i've tried if there is a way to access the different checkboxes in the grid, but i can't find a good function in this class.  my idea was to set a grid object in script and to change its values manually. for what i saw so far this can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either an entire column or an entire row of choices can be taken out manually or automatically in a grid item. So, unless your grid has only 1 row for the activity and then multiple columns across the top for all the times, you might want to consider working with a dropdown item instead and eliminate choices from that